# How get values from radio button in jsp and pass them to java servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have problem with passing values from jsp to java servlet.
My class Student has follow fields: id, firstName, lastName, precenseStatus.
Field precenseStatus is empty and a want to set "Obecny", "Nieobecny" or "Spóźniony" string value at it in jsp.
I pass to jsp list of Student object (students).

jsp:

```
<form action="updatePrecensesServlet" method="post">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Imię</th>
                    <th>Nazwisko</th>
                    <th>Obecność</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${student.firstName}"  /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${student.lastName}" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <form role="form">
                                <c:if test="${student.precenseStatus == 'Obecny'}">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input checked type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Obecny"/>Obecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Nieobecny"/>Nieobecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Spóźniony"/>Spóźniony
                                    </label>
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${student.precenseStatus == 'Nieobecny'}">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Obecny"/>Obecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input checked type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Nieobecny"/>Nieobecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Spóźniony"/>Spóźniony
                                    </label>
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${student.precenseStatus == 'Spó?niony'}">
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Obecny"/>Obecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Nieobecny"/>Nieobecny
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="radio-inline">
                                        <input checked type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Spóźniony"/>Spóźniony
                                    </label>
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${student.precenseStatus != 'Obecny' &&
                                              student.precenseStatus != 'Nieobecny' && 
                                              student.precenseStatus != 'Spó?niony'}">
                                      <label class="radio-inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Obecny"/>Obecny
                                      </label>
                                      <label class="radio-inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Nieobecny"/>Nieobecny
                                      </label>
                                      <label class="radio-inline">
                                          <input type="radio" name="${student.precenseStatus}" value="Spóźniony"/>Spóźniony
                                      </label>
                                </c:if>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button name="students" value="${student}" scope="request" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Zatwierdź</button>
    </form>
```

updatePrecensesServlet doPost():

```
System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("students").toString());
```

or

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("students").toString());
```

Not works :/

```
Student{ID=2, firstName=YYY, lastName=XXX, precenseStatus=null}
```

Comment: Those radio buttons doesn't have a name of `students`. Those radio buttons have a name of `${student.precenseStatus}`. Why? What exactly are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I pass follow list:

```
Student{ID=2, firstName=YYY, lastName=XXX, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=3, firstName=AAA, lastName=FFF, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=4, firstName=BBB, lastName=DDD, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=5, firstName=CCC, lastName=WWW, precenseStatus=null}
```

I expecting that I've got list of Students with set precenseStatus field.
for example:

```
Student{ID=2, firstName=YYY, lastName=XXX, precenseStatus=Obecny}
Student{ID=3, firstName=AAA, lastName=FFF, precenseStatus=Nieobecny}
Student{ID=4, firstName=BBB, lastName=DDD, precenseStatus=Obecny}
Student{ID=5, firstName=CCC, lastName=WWW, precenseStatus=Spóźniony}
```

But now is still:

```
Student{ID=2, firstName=YYY, lastName=XXX, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=3, firstName=AAA, lastName=FFF, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=4, firstName=BBB, lastName=DDD, precenseStatus=null}
Student{ID=5, firstName=CCC, lastName=WWW, precenseStatus=null}
```

I've selected all radio buttons in jsp of course. I don't left those radio buttons empty.

Comment: From where r u populating ${students} ?

Comment: According to me, you are not able to populate a {Student} in list of students

Comment: I populate list of Student (students) in servlet, then I pass this list to jsp. I want to supplement this on jsp page and response to post method in another servlet

Comment: A lot of radio buttons on one jsp page is a problem.